# How to pass greek letters in a stargazer table using Knitr?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, stargazer

In an `.Rnw` I am trying to build a table with value generated dynamically from R code. I would like to have greek letters names in my stargazer generated table.
(I am using R studio). The chunk in question looks like this.

> <>=
>   aux <- setNames(c(0.334,0.301,3.093,-0.242,0.049,0.018,0,0.012,0.022),                    c("$\beta_{0}$","kappa","mu","lambda","xi1","xi2","xi3","xi4","xi5"))
>
> stargazer(aux, title= "My Table", type="latex")
>   @

I am getting the following - and obviously the "beta" is not understood when compiling in pdf.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Comparison of results} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\$\$\textbackslash beta\_\{0\}\$\$ & kappa & mu & lambda & xi1 & xi2 & xi3 & xi4 & xi5 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$0.334$ & $0.301$ & $3.093$ & $$-$0.242$ & $0.049$ & $0.018$ & $0$ & $0.012$ & $0.022$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Try doubling the backslash: `"$\\beta_{0}$"`. A single `\b` is going to be interpreted by R itself as a backspace - see `?Quotes`.

Comment: I tried this one, but result is the same

Comment: See how your `\` in `\beta` is actually interpreted as `\textbackslash`? I have run into this issue as well with `xtable`. `R` is interpreting that you want `$\beta_{0}$` to appear exactly as "\beta_{0}" in the output `rnw` file. Your `type="latex"` means it will change everything so it appears as you have coded it in the latex output. Again, I'm not familiar with `stargazer` (so I'm sorry) but it seems that `stargazer` has a natural output it wants to follow that makes it easy to use re `?stargazer` and the stargazer vignette when you supply it with the data that is providing your values.